# Is it possible to use pinch to zoom Using Quartz 2D (CGrect)?

Tags: ios, quartz-2d, gestures

UIWebview allows pinch to zoom, but is it possible to use this gesture when using CGRect using Quartz 2d? and if so how?: All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You should be using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` in conjunction with functions to manipulate `CGAffineTransform` properties of objects. Using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` you can get zoom scale and apply a `CGAffineTransform` to `CGRect`. Following links should help you in doing so.
`UIPinchGestureRecognizer` for zooming http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more
For applying affine transform to `CGRect`, look into `CGRectApplyAffineTransform` method on https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html this reference page.